# How to tell LabVIEW to open a compiled app with a given fixed top-left coordinate?

Tags: build, labview

I want the front panel of a compiled app to always be centered the same when loaded.
However, when I compile a LabVIEW app, the default startup view of the compiled app depends on the position of the scroll bars of the development front panel window, so before I compile (build) I must re-position the scroll bars in the desired position...

How can I overcome this and set a fixed top-left or so coordinate for compiled apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First position your window sliders where you want them to be.

Get a reference to the VI's pane property (assuming you only have one). Use Index Array to get the first element which will be the reference to your main pane. Then get the Origin property from that.

When you initialize your executable, write this value to the Origin property.

[image]

[Here's a good thread about it.](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/how-to-get-the-front-panel-scroll-s-position-vallue/td-p/114858)